# How to fix Postgres Database not showing up in PgAdmin after making migrations and migrating with Django-Migrations

Tags: postgresql, docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose, pgadmin-4

I'm fairly new to Docker and I am trying to create a project with it and Django. My version of Django is 4.2 and I use the latest versions of PostgreSQL and Docker. So I created a `docker-compose.yml` file with Postgres-15 installed in it. I also have the database created on the PgAdmin application. I ran migrations and migrated with no issues. But when I opened the PgAdmin application, I could not see the newly created tables. They are absent as if they were not created. I did not encounter any error or anything when I ran migrations.

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=2030
      - POSTGRES_DB=ikenga_db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

 app:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
```

and the command I ran was:
`docker-compose run app python manage.py makemigrations` and `docker-compose run app python manage.py migrate`

This is my `settings.py` file:

```
from pathlib import Path
from typing import List

import dj_database_url
from pydantic import PostgresDsn
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings

class GeneralSettings(BaseSettings):
    DEBUG: bool = False
    SECRET_KEY: str 
    ALLOWED_HOSTS: List[str]
    DATABASE_URL: PostgresDsn


GENERAL_SETTINGS = GeneralSettings()


SECRET_KEY = GENERAL_SETTINGS.SECRET_KEY

DEBUG = GENERAL_SETTINGS.DEBUG

ALLOWED_HOSTS = GENERAL_SETTINGS.ALLOWED_HOSTS
```

And my `.env` file is this:

```
SECRET_KEY="+SV8S2ga3SgYMdJN1AOwwdZZoV5v0aM1eJh39yDxEzY="
ALLOWED_HOSTS='["localhost", "127.0.0.1", "0.0.0.0"]'
DEBUG=True

# database settings
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:2030@db:5432/ikenga_db
```

I tried to use ChatGPT to understand the situation, but I checked my docker-compose file and did not find any issues, I also checked my code and docker connection to the database and I think everything is on the right track.

I tried to shut down the containers and restart them, but that did not work.

Please if you can help me understand this, let me know what it is I'm doing wrong, I'd really like to understand this problem.

Comment: did you add same configurations in your settings.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I found out that the problem was I was trying to run Postgres on my local machine while in my docker container. Which is crazy! So all I needed to do to view PgAdmin in docker was to put a service for it in the `dockercompose.yml` file like so:

```
 pgadmin:
      image: dpage/pgadmin4
      environment:
        - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=pgadmin4@pgamin.org
        - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin
      ports:  
        - "5050:80"
```

then open the server via `localhost:5050` in the browser, log in using the email and password I specified in the `dockercompose.yml` file, then viola, I could see my PgAdmin interface and the database I created. This interface is the one that is running for the docker container. So next you gotta create your own server, using the procedures left from this great video, [Connecting postgres in docker to pgadmin server](https://youtu.be/2BjrT14Heug?si=LZ6j0T3vma1UNg6B)

I hope this helps someone too! Also the email and password are default for `dpage/admin`, though I did not try, but I think you can create your own specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try this docker-compose. I just fixed the indentation and added volumes at the end so that the db won't get flushed right away when you kill, or stop the container

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=2030
      - POSTGRES_DB=ikenga_db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  app:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Furthermore, you need to check your **settings.py** if the backend is being able to establish the connection to Postgres or not.

Comment: this did not help my problem but thank you for your contribution